Exported Map of ERC-3770 (Chain Prefixes)
I would like to know if the safe SDK suite exports a Map<chainId, ChainPrefix> so that we can generate links to safes by (chainId, address).
I've searched the safe-global github org for terms like "Chain Prefix" or "3770" and even some prefixes like "matic", but they do not return very promising results.

thanks for your great question.
There is a list of the network prefixes.
You can also use the function getEip3770NetworkPrefixFromChainId.
I hope this answers your question. Please mark your question answered in this case. We are also happy to provide further assistance, when you write another question or comment.
Have a great weekend!

Update: I found something here github which appears to be contained in NPM @safe-global/safe-core-sdk-utils but for any practical purpose I can think of its useless in its current state.

None of the exported functions actually perform the following basic operation
networks isn't directly exported and is empty in the build.

import { networks } from "@safe-global/safe-core-sdk-utils/dist/src/eip-3770/config";

export function eip3770Address(address: string, chainId: number): string {
  return `${networks[chainId]}:${address}`;
}

export function safeUrl(address: string, chainId: number): string {
  return `https://app.safe.global/home?safe=${eip3770Address(address, chainId)}`;
}

